# Is the smallest ellipsoid enclosing a convex set unique?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, analytic-geometry, ellipsoids

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex set. Assume that it is bounded. We want to find an ellipsoid $E$ of smallest volume such that $S \subset E$. Is $E$ unique?

Comment: When I tried this with the n dimensional simplex, the answer is yes and the ellipsoid is a hyper sphere.

Comment: I assume when you say $S$ is a convex set in $n$ dimensions you mean that $S$ itself is an $n$ dimensional set and are not merely repeating the fact that $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think the answer is affirmative. Assume the ellipsoid is not unique, $S\subset E_1$ and $S\subset E_2$. Then $S\subset(E_1\cap E_2)$, and if we show that some ellipsoid $E_3$ with $V(E_3)<V(E_1)$ encloses $E_1\cap E_2$, we are done.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Good point. I don't think it has to be solid, so I edited that out.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Seems like a good approach. You plan to continue that argument?

Comment: Must $S$ at least "span" $n$ dimensions then? What about $S=\{(-1,0),(1,0)\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$? Would the line segment connecting the two points be considered a degenerate ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @becko: I think I found a nice algebraic work-around.

Comment: I believe this is the theorem due to Fritz John. ... That is incorrect.  John's theorem is on an ellpsoiid of maximal volume contained within a convex body.

Comment: @GEdgar: well, then OP's claim is the dual version, about the minimal enclosing ellipsoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My claim is that the answer is affirmative by the following

> **Lemma.** If two different ellipsoids $E_1,E_2$ with the same (hyper-)volume intersect, there is some ellipsoid $E_3$ enclosing $E_1\cap E_2$ with the property that $V(E_3)< V(E_1)$.

Sketch of the proof: I will deal just with the 3D case. $E_1\cap E_2$ is described by something like:
$$ \left \{ \begin{array}{rcl}\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(z-z_0)^2}{c^2}&\leq& 1\\\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}+\frac{z^2}{C^2}&\leq& 1\end{array} \right.\tag{1}$$
where $abc=ABC$. Every point $(x,y,z)$ fulfilling the previous inequalities also fulfills
$$ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{x^2}{A^2}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}+\frac{y^2}{B^2}+\frac{(z-z_0)^2}{c^2}+\frac{z^2}{C^2}\leq 2, \tag{2} $$
that is the equation of an ellipsoid with volume depending on the product:
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2A^2}}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2b^2}+\frac{1}{2B^2}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2c^2}+\frac{1}{2C^2}}} \tag{3}$$
Through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or other means, it is not difficult to show that under the assumption $abc=ABC$, the previous product is $\leq abc$, with equality achieved only at $(a,b,c)=(A,B,C)$, proving the **Lemma**. Moreover, the approach is dimension-independent.

---

> Back to the original question: assuming that two different ellipsoids $E_1, E_2$ with the same minimal volume enclose $S$, the ellipsoid $E_3$ found through the above "averaging" procedure also encloses $S$, but $V(E_3)<V(E_1)$ contradicts the volume minimality of $E_1$.

This proves a sort of "dual" of [John's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid). I have just learned that the circumscribing ellipsoid with minimal volume is also known as the [Loewner-John ellipsoid](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86332/l%C3%B6wner-john-ellipsoid-incribed-and-circumscribed) $E^+$.

---

The above averaging procedure can also be improved by considering a convex combination of the equations appearing in $(1)$ that leads to the averaged ellipsoid $E_3$ with minimal volume. That probably also leads to an iterative algorithm for finding an enclosing ellipsoid with volume arbitrarily close to the minimum.

Comment: You should probably do it also for $n\ge 4$. The theorem (for arbitrary n) is due to John (or Loewner).

Comment: @studiosus: sure, this approach is dimension-independent. I showed only the $n=3$ case for simplicity.

Comment: It is easy to show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2a^2}+\frac{1}{2A^2}}}\leq\sqrt{aA}$$ is equivalent to $$\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{A}\right)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: I found the following two references: *L. Danzer, D. Laugwitz, and H. Lenz. Uber das Lownersche Ellipsoid und sein Analogon unter den einem Eikorper einbeschriebenen Ellipsoiden. Arch. Math., 8:214–219, 1957*, and  *V.L. Zaguskin. Circumscribed and inscribed ellipsoids of extremal volume. Usp. Mat. Nauk, 13(6 (84)):89–93, 1958*. One is german and the other russian, I can read neither :(

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0707

Comment: @becko: despite german/russian references, I think my answer is pretty straightforward to follow and clearly proves that the John-Loewner circumscribed ellipsoid $E^+$ is unique.